# Adding an empty List Box in razor view - @Html.ListBox("myLIstBox") throwing an error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, listbox

I am trying to add an empty ListBox to my Razor view page to store run time values. But It gives me an error message saying `There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'myListBox'`. I am aware that there is such viewdata. But, when I do the same with textbox, it works.

```
  @Html.TextBox("myTextBox")//works alright, displays a textbox 
  @Html.ListBox("myListBox") // gives error
```

How to display an empty listbox and why the above method works for textbox but for listbox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found a workaround to create an empty ListBox by passing an empty `SelectList` but still wondering why the original one did not work.

`@Html.ListBox("myListBox", new SelectList(new[]  {""}));`